# Shortest distance between point and a line in n-dimensions using generalised skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization, quadratic-forms, cross-product

Consider a line which passes through the origin and with direction vector $\vec g= G \vec f$ where $G$ is an $n+1$ by $n$ matrix of rank $n$

Consider a point $p$ in $n+1$ space

I'd like to find the $f$ which minimises the distance between the line and point $p$ over the sphere $f^{T}f=1$

If $g$ is three dimensional (it isn't in general) then I could use the distance equation:

$\frac {\Vert p\times Gf \Vert}{\Vert Gf \Vert}$

And i can introduce the skew-symmetric matrix for $p$ and also minimise the square instead to give:

$\frac {\Vert f^{T}G^{T} [p_\times]^{T}[p_\times] Gf \Vert}{\Vert f^{T}G^{T}Gf \Vert}$

where $[p_x]$ is the equivalent skew-symmetric matrix of cross product with $p$

I could then transform $f$ using cholseky decomposition of $G^{T}G$ and solve...

But i don't know how to do this in n-dimensions (i've tried to use the dot product formulation of distance to line without success).

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. This is an interesting problem. Thank you for stating it clearly and for sharing your ideas. Regarding $G$: I assume you want it to have rank $n$, not $n+1$. That said, the set of all lines with direction vectors of this form forms an $n$-dim subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ spanned by the columns of $G$. Find the closest point to $p$ on this subspace via normal projection, then find an $f$ such that this point is on the line with direction vector $Gf$.

Comment: Yes for rank of G..edited. Going to think through your latter statement.

Comment: OK thanks...I think i see why this gives the solution. I had been playing around with a harder problem whereby one of the components of  $g$ was not a linear function of $f$ but the square root of a quadratic form. I suppose in this case, it is now an $n$-dim surface? Do you think this is still solvable? And in an equivalent way ? Thank you (if its not clear i can expand the original question to include this secondary part)

Comment: Submit the modified version as a separate question. The objective function is possibly no longer convex after this modification.